# Button text not wrapping

Tags: jquery, css

I set up some templates a little while ago that the user of the application could edit the text of buttons among other things. A co-worker put a text editor in to make it a little more customization which is great. However this seems to have broken the button from expanding with the text and instead flows outside of it.

I have a feeling it's because the plugin only works off of div elements and the div inside the button is just making it act weird. I seem to be having quite a bit of trouble correcting this issue without creating more problems.

This is what it used to look like before the text editor

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-landing kiosk-btn" >
    <span class="control-label" contenteditable="true" data-bind="grabbing saved text with ko"></span>  
  </label>
</div>
```

and now it looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary btn-landing kiosk-btn" >
    <div class="control-label" contenteditable="true" data-bind="grabbing saved text with ko"></div>  
  </label>
</div>
```

I have tried putting a `display:inline` on the div as well as a `inline-block`. I have tried some other things as well, but nothing wants to work.

Comment: Can you reproduce it for us in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap inside the button? or do you want the button to expand?  It sounds like your title and description are conflicting.

Comment: Div class of control-label?

Comment: do you mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/e4ojv3qz/?

Comment: can we see the CSS behind 'btn-landing' and 'kiosk-btn'?

Comment: @jbutler483, that seems to break in Chrome if you remove all the text.

Comment: @doveyg: although not perfect, you could test if the text is empty, and do something  like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/e4ojv3qz/1/) although I would like confirmation this is what OP is looking for